# Wordpress get_users(); returning wrong users

Tags: wordpress

I have this call:

```
get_users('meta_key=main_feature&value=yes');
```

but the query is also returning users with the meta key 'featured' set to yes as well. I have a plugin that allows me to check all the user meta and have confirmed that the meta key for users that shouldn't be showing up is empty.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) says your arguments for the `get_users` function should be an array.

So your query should look somethin like this:

```
$args = (
    'meta_key' => 'main_feature',
    'value' => 'yes'
);
$users = get_users($args);
```

Comment: No, its not necessary, `meta_key=main_feature&value=yes` is correct way to pass argument.

Comment: It might be correct too, but the Docs say a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like below :

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'main_feature',
    'meta_value'   => 'yes',
    'meta_compare'  => 'EXISTS'
); 
$u = get_users($args);
```